# Looking for Documentation for Excel HTTP Response Headers

Tags: c#, .net, excel, http

I am having trouble finding documentation in regards to what types of headers and values Excel expects to determine what type of authentication to use or whether to authenticate at all.

For example, I have a web server that is home to excel files that require basic authentication to access.

Using a data link to reference a URL to the file for download prompts me the first time to provide credentials as expected. If I save the excel document and try to refresh the links, no prompt is used to authenticate and the document fails to connect the first time until I attempt to update the values a second time.

Does excel expect any specific headers to know to prompt for credentials without having to update values again at first load?

Comment: You mean you have a power query fetching some form of web contents? Or....?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am attempting to get data from a workbook on my server. This creates a Link available under Data -> Edit Links where I can update the values that are referenced from that link. I could for example, create a link to localhost/filename.xlsx

Where in excel I reference it as ='localhost/[filename.xlsx]SHEETNAME'!A1

When I update the values, excel downloads the file and updates the value in my worksheet. Unfortunately opening the workbook the first time throws an error while all future requests are successful.

Comment: It appears that my link will only provide the cached credentials after subsequent requests and never the first, even though it never prompts me for my credentials again.

Comment: Personally I'd take a step back, maybe simplify the problem by using a query to import a csv or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. This is being done in an attempt to support 1000s of documents that already have been configured with these types of references. The goal is to migrate the files to the new server that would match the url in these spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was achieved by adding WebDAV support to my application.

Excel will initially send a OPTIONS method request determining whether or not the server supports such features as Sharepoint or WebDAV.

Example responses are below:

```
HTTP/2 200
Method: OPTIONS
Path: /documents/filename.xlsx
Accept-Ranges: none
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD,LOCK,UNLOCK,CHECKIN,CHECKOUT,PROPFIND
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: dav, content-length, allow
Content-Length: 0
dav: 1,2
ms-author-via: DAV
x-engine: Application Server
```

After determining the communication protocol support, a PROPFIND request is sent. If authentication is required like in my case, we respond with a 401 error and the acceptable authentication.

```
HTTP/2 401
Method: PROPFIND
Path: /documents/filename.xlsx
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Warning: Authentication Required!
WWW-Authenticate:  Digest realm="Application-Server", nonce="#####", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
x-msdavext_error: 401; Authorization is required for this resource. Please authenticate using Bearer, Digest or Cookie based authentication.
ms-author-via: DAV
```

Basic authentication is being deprecated by Microsoft office so Digest was required.